# JavaScript - empty string how do I assign a changing value

Tags: javascript, string

I created a string
let clientName = ""

Then I have an input question
clientName = input.question ("What is your name? ")

The answer to the input question will change.  How do I get the answer to fill the empty string?

Comment: Declare your variable at global scope. Then when you get the answer back from the user, you can reassign the value to it. Or you could assign it to the window object. window.clientName = 'new value'. Or you could use localstorage or a document.cookie

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)?

```js
let clientName = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log(clientName)
```

Comment: This is what I did and now it works - I think
 let contactName= input.question.contactName 
contactName = input.question ("What is your name? ")

console.log (`Contact Name: ${contactName}`)

Comment: I don't see prompt() in there - it doesn't make sense to me unfortunately. Did you want the popup to ask the question or just have an input element (text box) where someone types it in?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>

<div>What is your name?</div>
  <input type="text" id="name" onchange="getName()" name="name" value="">

<script>

function getName() {

let clientName = "";
clientName= document.getElementById("name").value;
console.log(clientName);
}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should simply assign the new value like this:

```
clientName = //the new value you want assign to the client name
```